Is constructor in c++ a right value or left value
There's a String class like this:
class String
{
public:
  String() { }
  ...
  void test() && { std::cerr << "right version" << std::endl; }
  void test() & { std::cerr << "left version" << std::endl; }
  void test_ctor(String &&s) { std::cerr << "right version" << std::endl; }
  void test_ctor(const String &s) { std::cerr << "left version" << std::endl; }
  ...
private:
  ...
}

And main.cpp:
int main() 
{
  String().test();
  String lhs;
  lhs.test();

  ([]() -> String { return String(); })().test();

  lhs.test_ctor(lhs);
  lhs.test_ctor(String());
}

What kind of output will be?
And is String() a right value or a left value?
My output:
right version
left version
right version
left version
left version

That is
  String().test(); // right version
  String lhs;
  lhs.test(); // left version

  ([]() -> String { return String(); })().test(); // right version

  lhs.test_ctor(lhs); // left version
  lhs.test_ctor(String()); // left version

At String().test(), it's a right value.
At lhs.test_ctor(String()), it's a left value.
That's confusing.

It is always an rvalue and the last line will output "right version" as well. You must have not tested the code that you are actually showing.

Also, the terms are "lvalue" and "rvalue". Historically they may have originated from "right" and "left", but that has no practical meaning any more.

See https://godbolt.org/z/GEdqnfGo5.

@user17732522 Thanks a lot! I checked my code in IDE and you're right.

Also you may have misunderstood the meaning of && and & after the member function parameter list. It tells the compiler about the value category of the operand on which the member function is called. It has nothing to do with the parameter (lhs) and String() that you're passing in the last two calls.

Regarding this line:
lhs.test_ctor(String()); // left version

You seems to be mistaken.
String() is an rvalue, and therefore the line above will print:
right version

See demo.
Note:
The correct terminology is rvalue and lvalue (not "right value" and "left value", although the "r" and "l" origin from these words).
See some more information about C++ value categories here.


And is String() a right value or a left value?

String() is an rvalue expression. Also note that the terms "left value" and "right value" are not formally used in c++. The correct terms are lvalue and rvalue.

At String().test(), it's a right value. At lhs.test_ctor(String()), it's a left value. That's confusing.

You've misunderstood the meaning of && and & after the member function parameter list. It tells the compiler about the value category of the operand on which the member function is called. It has nothing to do with the parameter (lhs) and String() that you're passing in the last two calls.
In the call String().test(), the member function is called on/using an rvalue String() so it prints the right version.
While in the call lhs.test_ctor(String()), it is called on an lvalue so it prints the left version.
I would also recommend using a Good c++ book
